# cast/convert from varchar to numeric with not enough decimal spaces?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I had a file imported into a staging table and the import made all of the numeric fields of type varchar. Those numeric fields eventually have to go to a field that is defined as numeric(28,6), and I will not be able to change the target.

The problem I'm having is that a few fields have more than 6 decimal places.

There's always the brute force method of testing each row for how many decimal places it has and only taking what you can use. Does anyone know of a better way of tackling the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you actually getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL will automatically round any extra decimal places during implicit or explicit conversion... you shouldn't need to do any testing.

```
DECLARE
    @VarcharField VARCHAR(50),
    @NumericField NUMERIC(28,6)

SET @VarcharField = '123456789.123456789'
SET @NumericField = @VarcharField

PRINT @NumericField

-- OUTPUT
-- 123456789.123457
```

Answer (score 0):

It's okay if the input values have more than 6 decimal places, unless I'm misunderstanding you.

You could just do:

```
select convert(decimal(28,6),'17897986056.1235246346')
```

Comment: Yeah, I became aware of that from Michael's answer above as well.  Thank you for taking time to add the information.  I left my answer there as an example of explicitly converting versus relying upon the implicit behaviors but you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to exclude those rows? If not, I would simply use the ROUND function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx). This gives you the ability to truncate the additional numbers or round up if you wish.

Comment: I thought it might not be, but was trying to understand what problem he could be encountering. I fixed my answer to include that the ROUND function gives you the ability to decide how to round. Also, I unfortunately do not have enough reputation to simply add a comment.